# Get average of sub values in python nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, evaluation

I have a situation where I have a table (imported from excel) wit requirments and sub requirments, it could be seen like this example:

```
+-------------+--------+
| Requeriment | Points |
+-------------+--------+
| 1           |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 2           |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 3           |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 3.1         |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 3.2         |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 3.3         |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 4           |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 5           |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 5.1         |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 5.2         |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 5.2.1       |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 5.2.1.1     |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 5.3         |        |
+-------------+--------+
| 6           |        |
+-------------+--------+
```

All requeriment max value is '1.0', if there are a case where the requirments have  sub requirments, the requirments value = sum(subrequirments)/total subrequirments and it apply also to the sub requirments wit sub requirments.

Here I show how the requirments with no sub requirments are evaluated with a 0 if it is not complete and 1.0 if it is completed.

[image]

The requirments with sub requirments will be evaluated whith a formula:
requeriment point = sum of sub requeriments/value of sub requeriments. the value will be some like this:

[image]

This table were converted in a dictionary like this:

```
{requeriments:{
 '1':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {}},
 '2':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {}},
 '3':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {
    '3.1':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {} },
    '3.2':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {} },
    '3.3':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {} }
   }
  },
 '4':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {}},
 '5':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {
    '5.1':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {} },
    '5.2':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {
      '5.2.1':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {
         '5.2.1.1':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {}
         }

        } 
      },
    '5.3':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {} }
   }
  },
 '6':{'points':'', subrequeriments: {}}
 }
}
```

At the end I can not get a good way to evaluate the requirments aplying the function requirment value = sum(subrequirments)/total subrequirments in the nested sub requirments.

Do you know a good way to aply it to a dictionary or at least a good way do do it to a lost or a table?

Comment: Can you give an example of what your expected output would be? E.g. what is the value that you would want for '5', '5.1', '5.2', '5.2.1', and '5.2.1.1'? Seem like a problem that can be solved in a pretty straightforward manner with recursion but I'm not following exactly what algorithm should be applied to get the value.

Comment: Just a heads up, it's spelled `requirement` not `requeriment`.

Comment: `All requeriment max value is '1.0'` is unclear. Can you explain what this means?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? You apparently already have some code that processes the table into the dictionary? Or are you asking how to do that as well? Please focus on a single problem, and share code you already wrote, with data that's representative of the data you are actually working on. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have make edits in this post, you can see the answer to some of your doubts.

Comment: how do you know that a requirement is complete or not? that's the data you are given? it was false for 5.2, how do you know you can trust the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive function:

```
def calcPoints(d):
    points = 0
    for k,v in d.items():
        if v['points'] == '':
            v['points'] = calcPoints(v['subrequirements'])
        points += float(v['points'])
    return str(points / max(1,len(d)))
```

Input:

```
data = {'requeriments': 
{'1': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
 '2': {'points': '0', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
 '3': {'points': '', 'subrequirements': 
    {'3.1': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}},
     '3.2': {'points': '0', 'subrequirements': {}},
     '3.3': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}}}, 
 '4': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
 '5': {'points': '', 'subrequirements': 
    {'5.1': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}},
     '5.2': {'points': '', 'subrequirements': 
          {'5.2.1': {'points': '', 'subrequirements': 
                  {'5.2.1.1': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
                   '5.2.1.2': {'points': '0', 'subrequirements': {}}}}, 
           '5.2.2': {'points': '0', 'subrequirements': {}}}},
     '5.3': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}}}, 
 '6': {'points': '0', 'subrequirements': {}}}}
```

Output:

```
calcPoints(data['requeriments']) # '0.5694444444444444'

print(data)

{'requeriments': 
 {'1': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
  '2': {'points': '0', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
  '3': {'points': '0.6666666666666666', 'subrequirements': 
     {'3.1': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
      '3.2': {'points': '0', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
      '3.3': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}}}, 
  '4': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
  '5': {'points': '0.75', 'subrequirements': 
     {'5.1': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
      '5.2': {'points': '0.25', 'subrequirements': 
           {'5.2.1': {'points': '0.5', 'subrequirements': 
                   {'5.2.1.1': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}, 
                    '5.2.1.2': {'points': '0', 'subrequirements': {}}}}, 
            '5.2.2': {'points': '0', 'subrequirements': {}}}}, 
      '5.3': {'points': '1', 'subrequirements': {}}}}, 
  '6': {'points': '0', 'subrequirements': {}}}}
```

Comment: Thaks, your answer help me to learn how to use the recursive functions in a dictionary, thank you very much